# Python Parse weather station data to dataframe and save in Postgresql

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, parsing

How do I pasre the following data obtained as result of API query into a column name (column units) followed by values as cell values.

```
wea_data = [{'observation_time': '2023-05-09T15:55:00.000000+00:00',
  'station': 'KCOF',
  'weather_results': {'@id': 'https://api.weather.gov/stations/KCOF/observations/2023-05-09T15:55:00+00:00',
                      '@type': 'wx:ObservationStation',
                      'barometricPressure': {'qualityControl': 'V',
                                             'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:Pa',
                                             'value': 101800},
                      'cloudLayers': [{'amount': 'CLR',
                                       'base': {'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:m',
                                                'value': None}}],
                      'dewpoint': {'qualityControl': 'V',
                                   'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:degC',
                                   'value': 17.9},
                      'elevation': {'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:m', 'value': 3},
                      'heatIndex': {'qualityControl': 'V',
                                    'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:degC',
                                    'value': 28.657944011208333},
                      'icon': 'https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/skc?size=medium',
                      'maxTemperatureLast24Hours': {'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:degC',
                                                    'value': None},
                      'minTemperatureLast24Hours': {'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:degC',
                                                    'value': None},
                      'precipitationLast3Hours': {'qualityControl': 'Z',
                                                  'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:mm',
                                                  'value': None},
                      'precipitationLast6Hours': {'qualityControl': 'Z',
                                                  'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:mm',
                                                  'value': None},
                      'precipitationLastHour': {'qualityControl': 'Z',
                                                'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:mm',
                                                'value': None},
                      'presentWeather': [],
                      'rawMessage': 'KCOF 091555Z AUTO 33005KT 10SM CLR 28/18 '
                                    'A3006 RMK AO2 SLP184 T02780179 $',
                      'relativeHumidity': {'qualityControl': 'V',
                                           'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:percent',
                                           'value': 54.878330638989},
                      'seaLevelPressure': {'qualityControl': 'V',
                                           'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:Pa',
                                           'value': 101840},
                      'station': 'https://api.weather.gov/stations/KCOF',
                      'temperature': {'qualityControl': 'V',
                                      'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:degC',
                                      'value': 27.8},
                      'textDescription': 'Clear',
                      'timestamp': '2023-05-09T15:55:00+00:00',
                      'visibility': {'qualityControl': 'C',
                                     'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:m',
                                     'value': 16090},
                      'windChill': {'qualityControl': 'V',
                                    'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:degC',
                                    'value': None},
                      'windDirection': {'qualityControl': 'V',
                                        'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:degree_(angle)',
                                        'value': 330},
                      'windGust': {'qualityControl': 'Z',
                                   'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:km_h-1',
                                   'value': None},
                      'windSpeed': {'qualityControl': 'V',
                                    'unitCode': 'wmoUnit:km_h-1',
                                    'value': 9.36}}}]
```

Comment: What variables do you want to extract?

Comment: @Corralien I want to extract all variables. Put them nicely in this format:  Of course, some variables does not have this format `column name (column units)     value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example of turning the `weather_results` first observation into column dictionary:

```
cols = {}
for k, v in wea_data[0]["weather_results"].items():
    if type(v) == dict:
        for sub_k, sub_v in v.items():
            if sub_v is None or type(sub_v) in (str, int, float):
                cols[f"{k}_{sub_k}"] = sub_v

for c in cols:
    print(c, cols[c])
```

Comment: Do you know what `quality control` mean in the above data?

Comment: No idea what `quality_control` means, should be detailed on the API site.